# FFmpeg H264 lossless y channel

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I want to encode a video using H264 encoding of FFmpeg. My problem is to keep the information in y channel (intensity) as much as possible. I don't care much about the color information in the video.

I tried lossless encoding, but the file size became too large. For example, the size of a 10 secs video became 30,3 MByte (~24 Kbps).

I didn't see any option for H264 in FFMpeg to encode intensity information of a video in a lossless way. Do you know any option setting to preserve intensity information in a lossless way while keeping the file size small?

Comment: Can you discard the chroma altogether?

Comment: Actually, i don't want to lose color information. I tried yuv420p that is encoded with 12bits/pixel. I also tried yuv410p (9 bits/pixel), but ffmpeg gives a warning that H.264 does not support yuv410p.